# A boy ran into a chair & made the chair fall off, can we say "you fell the chair"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> **[fall](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fall_1?q=fall)** [intransitive] to suddenly stop standing
>
> She slipped on the ice and fell.
>
> A tree fell, just missing his car.
>
> fall + adv./prep. I fell over and cut my knee.
>
> The house looked as if it was about to fall down.

---

Now, a boy ran into a chair & made the chair fall off, can we say "**you fell the chair**"?

I know that the verb "**fall**" is not a transitive verb. So, we can say "**The chair fell**" but we can not say "**I fell the chair**".

What is the equivalent expression of "**to make the chair fall**"?

Comment: Funnily enough, _fell_ does exist and originally was a causitive of _fall_, so it meant _cause to fall_. But now it is an archaic word except when used ot trees.

Comment: You *could* say "you felled the chair". It's unconventional but functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean "made the chair fall over". The typical way to say it would be "you knocked down the chair". Depending on the exact action, you could also say "you pushed the chair over". In other words, you describe the boy's actions, not trying to force "fall" into the sentence.

Just to confuse you, there is difference between "to fall" and "to fell". Fell in this case, actually does mean what you think, but we wouldn't normally use it with a chair.

Comment: knock down the chair is not typical. You can knock down a thing or person. Typical would be: to knock the chair over

Comment: @Lambie, seem, knock down / over are the same https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/knock-over?q=knock+over

Comment: I think "knock something down" works okay if the thing is somehow suspended, or otherwise high up. There was a mirror hanging on the wall but I knocked it down. Or, he was standing on the box when he got knocked down.

Comment: Why give the best answer first, *made the chair fall over*, which is a very common expression, and then for the official answer provide a clumsy, uncommon expression, *knocked down the chair*?  *Knocked the chair over, Toppled the chair,* those all work.  We **knock down** walls, barriers, obstacles, and abandoned buildings but as a general rule we do not knock down chairs.

Comment: @Tom - Your Oxford link does not support your point.  *To hit somebody and make them fall to the ground*.  This applies to *somebody* that is true but it does not apply to every *something*.  It has much to do with the shape of the object.